# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'exports'

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I migrate Angular 1.5 app from RquireJS 2.2 to Webpack 3. And I want to setup a Webpack environment which will support the current RequireJS code and transit to Webpack+ES6 gradually, step by step, writing tests and refactoring the source code.

Now when I try to generate a bundle by `webpack` command I get the following error:

```
user@host:~/dev/myapp$ webpack 
Hash: 3ac8a9bb3d386514f8a6
Version: webpack 3.4.1
Time: 101ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  10.7 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./app/bootstrap.js 82 bytes {0} [built]
   [2] ./app/app.js 7.37 kB {0} [built]
    + 1 hidden module

ERROR in ./app/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'services/routeResolver' in '/home/trex/dev/myapp/app'
 @ ./app/app.js 3:0-175:2
 @ ./app/bootstrap.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/angular/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'exports' in '/home/trex/dev/myapp'
 @ ./node_modules/angular/index.js 1:0-20
 @ ./app/bootstrap.js
```

How can I set the exports in my case?

App structure:

```
user@host:~/dev$ tree -L 1 myapp
theapp
├── app
├── css
├── font-awesome
├── fonts
├── img
├── index.html
├── lang
├── lib
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── resources
├── scripts
├── share
├── templates
├── tests
└── widgets
```

Some libraries are in `node_modules`, other in `lib` folder. All the libraries linked directly in index.html: 
`<script type="application/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.min.js" ></script>`

Webpack config:

```
user@host:~/dev$ cat myapp/webpack.config.js 
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/bootstrap.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            { test: /[\/]angular\.js$/, loader: "exports?angular" }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {},
      extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
      modules: [
        'node_modules',
        'lib'
      ]
    }
};
```

Pieces of the source code:

- myapp/app/app.js https://gist.github.com/sergibondarenko/a87578e774ca43f4fc8a105fa163e13c
- myapp/app/main.js https://gist.github.com/sergibondarenko/9ea25e6ac4f57a7f2703e053efe48ca
- myapp/app/controllers/loginController.js https://gist.github.com/sergibondarenko/7c5df871c96f4e9919900f8f87d53a8b

**--- UPDATE**

I converted the code to ES6.

- myapp/app/app.js
  https://gist.github.com/sergibondarenko/73aa1ba06250c1d347bc44c7b9361c79
- myapp/app/main.js
  https://gist.github.com/sergibondarenko/ac290eb35f633337edd6ec8d15ccd13b
- myapp/app/controllers/loginController.js
  https://gist.github.com/sergibondarenko/9c995b4cab2de5d48905bac51c929155

And now I have the following error:

```
user@host:~/dev/myapp$ webpack
Hash: 673f49fc25bd759ea99d
Version: webpack 3.4.1
Time: 118ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  18.2 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [1] ./app/bootstrap.js 78 bytes {0} [built]
   [2] ./app/app.js 7.35 kB {0} [built]
   [3] ./app/services/routeResolver.js 7.07 kB {0} [built]
    + 1 hidden module

ERROR in ./node_modules/angular/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'exports' in '/home/trex/dev/myspp'
 @ ./node_modules/angular/index.js 1:0-20
 @ ./app/bootstrap.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack fails to import module `services/routeResolver`, which defined as dependency in your `app.js` AMD module.

You can try to use automatic converters from AMD to ES6, like this https://github.com/jonbretman/amd-to-as6 or this https://github.com/buxlabs/amd-to-es6

Comment: can you provide bootstrap.js and ./node_modules/angular/index.js files? What exactly angular version at node_modules?